# Removing "." and ".." in work with directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to write a program that get from user a path and then go to that directory and all of subdirectories recurcively and collect all txt files. but "." and ".." bother me when I am iterating directories recurcively. please help me to eradicating this problem.
this is my code :

```
def detect_files(path)
            Dir.foreach(path) do |i|
        if (i != "." or i !="..")
            if (File.directory?(i))
                detect_files(i)
            end
            if (i.reverse.start_with?("txt."))
                @files[i]=[]
            end
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: Instead of wrapping the complete block into an if-statement, you should consider using `next if <inverse-condition>` instead. That saves you one level of indentation and makes your code more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition should be :

```
if (i != "." and i != "..")
```

- If `i="."` then `i != "."` will be false making the condition false, and `"."` will not be processed
- If `i=".."` then `i != "."` will be true but `i != ".."` will be false, making the condition false and `".."` will not be processed.
- If `i` has any other values, then both side of `and` will be true and the body of `if` will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dir.foreach(path) do |i|
  next if %w(. ..).include?(i)
  # rest of your code
end
```

Your current version has a wrong condition for the `if`: you want `(i != '.' AND i != '..')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
all_txt_files = Dir['**/*.txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try just doing something like this

```
def detect_files(path)
  p1 = File.join(path, '**', '*.txt')
  @files = Dir[p1]
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Dir.foreach('/path/to/dir') do |item|
  next if item == '.' or item == '..'
  # do work on real items
end
```

OR

```
Dir.glob('/path/to/dir/*.rb') do |rb_file|
  # do work on files ending in .rb in the desired directory
end
```